# Problems while upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. But i'm facing some problems.

```
nuc ➜  ~  sudo apt update                              
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                 
Fetched 88,7 kB in 0s (164 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1919 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
nuc ➜  ~  sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Conflicts: packagekit
                              Conflicts: packagekit:i386
E: Broken packages
```

I have tried to remove the conflicting packages:

```
nuc ➜  ~  sudo apt remove packagekit packagekit:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'packagekit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'packagekit:i386' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1919 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic (4.15.0-45.48) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic (4.15.0-45.48) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
cp: failed to restore the default file creation context: Invalid argument
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
cp: failed to restore the default file creation context: Invalid argument
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any advice would be helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

I tried spinState010's suggestion but it didn't resolve this same issue for me.  What did was:

```
sudo apt remove python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
```

So, you might give that a try instead and let us know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your important files and file system are backed up before doing a distro update. I recommend using `rsync` for any type of file system backups. Have you tried

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```